# how to change tab colour on click in vue js

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this tab that hide and show component, I'm trying to change the text color to red when a tab is active and has been clicked

this is my component

```
<div @click="visibleComponent='transactions'":class="{ active: 'red'}" class="font-weight-400 font-size-16 line-height-24 white">
    Wallet
</div>
<div @click="visibleComponent='bankAccount'":class="opacity-25 padding-left-20 font-weight-400 font-size-16 line-height-24 blue">
    Bank Account
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to change each tab's text color when any one tab is active?

Comment: yes that what i want to do @NehaSoni

Answer (score 0):

Use condition in class binding

```
:class="{ visibleComponent === 'transactions' : 'bg-blue'}"
```

If `visibleComponent === 'transactions'` return `true` this tab get `bg-blue` class. And if you want set it class to other tab when it is active use `:class="{ visibleComponent === 'bankAccount' : 'bg-blue'}"` on it

Comment: getting Unexpected token, expected ","

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use your `visibleComponent` variable to do this-

1. By default set `visibleComponent` to `null` which means no tab is selected initially.
2. Now, on every tab's click, you are setting some value to `visibleComponent` which means a tab is going to be active.
3. On each tab, bind a class named `tab-color` that will be applied when `visibleComponent` would have some value. It means on any tab's click, all tabs would have this 'tab-color' class which will turn the text color to red for all tabs.
4. Finally, create a class named `tab-color` in CSS and write the color property inside it.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div
      @click="visibleComponent='transactions'"
      :class="{ 'tab-color': visibleComponent }"
      class="font-weight-400 font-size-16 line-height-24 white"
    >
      Wallet Transactions
    </div>
    <div
      @click="visibleComponent='bankAccount'"
      :class="{ 'tab-color': visibleComponent }"
      class="opacity-25 padding-left-20 font-weight-400 font-size-16 line-height-24 blue"
    >
      Bank Account
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
.tab-color {
  color: red;
}
</style>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      visibleComponent: null
    }
  }
}
</script>
```